# knockoutjs Form Example with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, knockout.js

I am trying to create a simple form with Knockoutjs that will pass a bit of user information with AJAX.
Does someone have an example that has three fields (firstname, lastname, postal-code).  It can take these three fields from the server if available or load blank.  Then take these same three fields put them in an object and post with AJAX.

```
    function UserInfo(data){
       this.firstname = ko.observable(data.firstname);
       this.lastname = ko.observable(data.lastname);
       this.postal-code = ko.observable(data.postal-code);
     }
     function UserInfoViewModel()
     {
        //Do stuff here to save up
     }
```

I am really just looking for a simple example. But everytime I look it is loading arrays of stuff.  The examples seem to just skip the standard form example with some AJAX.  If I can see a best practise way of basically making a crud form I can run with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your code you should use [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). ko.mapping allows you to 'convert' plain object into object with observables.

In your case would that :

```
var UserInfo = function (data) {
    // add a self property, it is really helpful when you need to refer the current viewmodel (eg in ajax callback) 
    var self = this;
    // ko.mapping.fromJS creates for all properties in data an observable in self.
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);        
    // the above line do that : 
    /*
        self.firstname = ko.observable(data.firstname);
        ...
    */

    self.save = function () {
        // ko.mapping.toJS converts the viewmodel (with observables) into plain object.
        var raw = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
        $.ajax('url', { data: raw })
            .done(function () {
            // in this context 'this' refers to window, but you can use 'self'.
            alert("success");
        });
    };
};

var initialData = {
    firstname: 'firstname ',
    lastname: 'lastname',
    'postal-code': 'postal-code'
};

var ui = new UserInfo(initialData );
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**View:**

```
<button data-bind="click : $data.save">Save</button>
```

**Model**

```
self.save()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "url/saveUser",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
           firstname : self.firstname(),
           lastname: self.lastname(),
           postalCode: self.postalCode()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("OK!")
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
        {
           alert("Not OK!")    
        }
}
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SC6WU/)